# Changing HTML components to Standard components

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a MVC-3 application (Once we create it we are given a login screen which is already developed). And it has used HTML components found in the toolbox to create text boxes, labels etc. But i want to use standard components found in the toolbox. How can i replace these HTML components with the standard components.

When the user clicks on the Login button, the username and password gets authenticated in the default sample application provided for us. I don't want to change its functionality but what i want is only to change the form components to the Standard components found in the toolbox.

How can i do this ?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: What?  Html component versus standard component?  What toolbar?

Comment: Typo, it should be ToolBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about these:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
```

These are called Html helpers.  They are used in asp.net mvc to generate html that will play nice with the mvc model binder.  If you want to replace them with plain html, you can always view source, see what the rendered html is and paste it in its place, though I don't personally see the point.  Nothing good could come of this.

But this is what the two lines above render:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Les see if I undesrtand, If when you say standard controls you mean ASP.NET Server Side Controls you can't I mean at least not using MVC and the reason is 'cause is like mixing apples and bananas you have to use either WebForms or MVC, if you choose MVC so you have to place the logic in a controller on an specific action that is going to be called once the form the button is inside of is clicked,but if you dont want to, so use a plain old aspx page add server side controls and put the logic on the click event of the button, but you can't mix MVC and WebForms that makes no sense (I'm saying this in a good way :) ) they're different paradigms.

Comment: If i use it like this `    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
` is this Ok ?

Comment: You can't use <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> on MVC, MVC is a total different approach, if you want you can use asp.net server side controls (asp:TextBox) then move the login logic to the asp:Button click event. You can't mix MVC and WeForms, actually you shouldn't.